# how to build conditional rolling sequence in character form in R

Tags: r, string, iteration, conditional-statements, rolling-computation

I have a data frame with 4 columns

`g` represents some group id in the data

`x` represents some character type id on which I have to perform computation

`date` is date of action, to be used for some other analysis.  (however, I have retained the same so that the order of records may be preserved)

`action` is action to be performed.  This column has two values 'add' and 'reduce'.  These are equal in number for each group `g`.  Means if there are 5 records having 'add' then there will be 5 'reduce' in the same group.  recorded as an ordered factor in data frame.

Basically, I have to create a new column by the following rules-

- *Since first record in each group will always be 'add' therefore exact value of `x` may be used here*
- *In second and onward record, in each group, the value of `x` may be pasted to previous record given that 'action' value is 'add'*
- *In second and onward record, in each group, the value of `x` may be removed from previous record given that 'action' value is 'reduce'*

`dput` of sample data is

```
df <- structure(list(g = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L), x = c("1_", "1_", "2_", "2_", "2_", "1_", "2_", "1_", 
"1_", "1_", "1_", "2_", "2_", "2_", "1_", "2_", "3_", "3_", "3_", 
"3_", "4_", "4_", "3_", "3_", "3_", "3_", "3_", "3_", "4_", "5_", 
"4_", "5_", "6_", "6_", "6_", "6_", "7_", "7_", "7_", "7_", "8_", 
"8_", "8_", "8_"), date = structure(c(18262, 18264, 18265, 18266, 
18271, 18275, 18275, 18276, 18277, 18279, 18280, 18283, 18286, 
18287, 18288, 18291, 18262, 18264, 18275, 18276, 18277, 18288, 
18275, 18283, 18291, 18297, 18301, 18309, 18366, 18374, 18375, 
18381, 18309, 18319, 18328, 18347, 18364, 18367, 18303, 18309, 
18328, 18341, 18341, 18344), class = "Date"), action = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("add", 
"reduce"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), groups = structure(list(g = 1:8, .rows = structure(list(
    1:16, 17:22, 23:28, 29:32, 33:36, 37:38, 39:40, 41:44), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df
# A tibble: 44 x 4
# Groups:   g [8]
       g x     date       action
   <int> <chr> <date>     <ord> 
 1     1 1_    2020-01-01 add   
 2     1 1_    2020-01-03 add   
 3     1 2_    2020-01-04 add   
 4     1 2_    2020-01-05 add   
 5     1 2_    2020-01-10 reduce
 6     1 1_    2020-01-14 reduce
 7     1 2_    2020-01-14 reduce
 8     1 1_    2020-01-15 reduce
 9     1 1_    2020-01-16 add   
10     1 1_    2020-01-18 add   
# ... with 34 more rows
```

`desired result` may be like -

```
head(as_tibble(df3_r),12)
# A tibble: 12 x 6
       X     g x     date       action result  
   <int> <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   
 1     1     1 1_    01-01-2020 add    1_      
 2     2     1 1_    03-01-2020 add    1_1_    
 3     3     1 2_    04-01-2020 add    1_1_2_  
 4     4     1 2_    05-01-2020 add    1_1_2_2_
 5     5     1 2_    10-01-2020 reduce 1_1_2_  
 6     6     1 1_    14-01-2020 reduce 1_2_    
 7     7     1 2_    14-01-2020 reduce 1_      
 8     8     1 1_    15-01-2020 reduce NA      
 9     9     1 1_    16-01-2020 add    1_      
10    10     1 1_    18-01-2020 add    1_1_    
11    11     1 1_    19-01-2020 reduce 1_      
12    12     1 2_    22-01-2020 add    1_2_
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `accumulate2` from the `purrr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(result = unlist(accumulate2(
    x, action[-1L], ~if (..3 == "add") paste0(., .y) else sub(.y, "", .)
  )))
```

Output

```
   g  x       date action   result
1  1 1_ 2020-01-01    add       1_
2  1 1_ 2020-01-03    add     1_1_
3  1 2_ 2020-01-04    add   1_1_2_
4  1 2_ 2020-01-05    add 1_1_2_2_
5  1 2_ 2020-01-10 reduce   1_1_2_
6  1 1_ 2020-01-14 reduce     1_2_
7  1 2_ 2020-01-14 reduce       1_
8  1 1_ 2020-01-15 reduce         
9  1 1_ 2020-01-16    add       1_
10 1 1_ 2020-01-18    add     1_1_
11 1 1_ 2020-01-19 reduce       1_
12 1 2_ 2020-01-22    add     1_2_
13 1 2_ 2020-01-25 reduce       1_
14 1 2_ 2020-01-26    add     1_2_
15 1 1_ 2020-01-27 reduce       2_
16 1 2_ 2020-01-30 reduce         
17 2 3_ 2020-01-01    add       3_
18 2 3_ 2020-01-03    add     3_3_
19 2 3_ 2020-01-14 reduce       3_
20 2 3_ 2020-01-15 reduce         
21 2 4_ 2020-01-16    add       4_
22 2 4_ 2020-01-27 reduce         
23 3 3_ 2020-01-14    add       3_
24 3 3_ 2020-01-22 reduce         
25 3 3_ 2020-01-30    add       3_
26 3 3_ 2020-02-05 reduce         
27 3 3_ 2020-02-09    add       3_
28 3 3_ 2020-02-17 reduce         
29 4 4_ 2020-04-14    add       4_
30 4 5_ 2020-04-22    add     4_5_
31 4 4_ 2020-04-23 reduce       5_
32 4 5_ 2020-04-29 reduce         
33 5 6_ 2020-02-17    add       6_
34 5 6_ 2020-02-27    add     6_6_
35 5 6_ 2020-03-07 reduce       6_
36 5 6_ 2020-03-26 reduce         
37 6 7_ 2020-04-12    add       7_
38 6 7_ 2020-04-15 reduce         
39 7 7_ 2020-02-11    add       7_
40 7 7_ 2020-02-17 reduce         
41 8 8_ 2020-03-07    add       8_
42 8 8_ 2020-03-20 reduce         
43 8 8_ 2020-03-20    add       8_
44 8 8_ 2020-03-23 reduce
```

Comment: Seems like it will work.  Thanks.  Please tell me what do `..3` works here, because I may have to modify the statement according to actual name and place in data.frame.

Comment: One more thing, Is there any need to apply group_by on `g` ?

Comment: The data in your example is already grouped so I didn't apply group_by on `g`. If you need to do this by group, then, of course, you need to `group_by`. That formula you saw is a `purrr` style function shorthand. `..1, .x, or .` represent the first argument. `..2 or .y` represent the second argument; `..3` means the third argument. @AnilGoyal

Comment: That function shorthand is equivalent to `function(out, xi, ai) if (ai == "add") paste0(out, xi) else sub(xi, "", out)`, if this makes more sense to you. @AnilGoyal

Comment: Yes, thanks a ton.  I need to learn `purrr` very soon.